# Trying to initiate a variable on page load Angularjs

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, angularjs

I am trying to initiate a variable showName when the page loads. It worked fine when I did it using just angular but when I implemented it with rails(with embedded ruby tags)  I am not able to hide the text field and save button as my variable gets undefined. I have tried couple of ways and ended with no result.

Here is my code. Any help is really appreciated. Thanks.

Edit.html.erb:

```
<div class="row" ng-controller="EditUserCtrl">
<div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3" id="editForm">
    <%= form_for(@user) do |f| %>
        <h1 id="editHeader">Account Information </h1>
        <%= render 'shared/error_messages' %>
        <div class="form-group">
            <%= f.label :name, "Full Name:" %><br>
            <div class="row">

                <div class="col-sm-7">
                    <div ng-hide="showName">
                        <%= f.label :name, @user.name , id:"editFields" %>
                    </div>
                    <%= f.text_field :name, { :'ng-show' => 'showName'}%>
                </div>

                <div class="col-sm-5" ng-show="showName">
                    <%= f.button "Save", :action => "update_name" , :method => :put, class: "btn btn-primary", :'ng-click' => "clicked()", id:"editAccount" %>
                </div>

                <div class="col-sm-5" ng-hide="showName">
                    <a href="" ng-click="editName()" ng-hide="showName"> <i id="nav-cart-count" class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit"></i> Edit </a>
                </div>

            </div>
        </div>
    <% end %>
</div>
```

Comment: I am confused.  This implementation has both rails and AngularJS.  Are you looking for the entire snippet to be only rails without any Angular?  If so, why does the Angular solution not work?

Comment: what changed? Don't know why you would convert all this to ruby in the first place but final result shouldn't be any different than what you had working before. All the browser sees is html so that should be the same

Comment: I mean even changing the ruby tags to normal html tags it didn't work on rails but when I tried the same code as a normal html file it worked.

Comment: Did you try initiating $scope.showName = true; (or false) in your controller?

Comment: Yes, I have that as my first step in the controller.

Answer (score 0):

Use ng-init to initialize the variable

```
<div class="row" ng-controller="EditUserCtrl" ng-init="showName = true">
```

Comment: I tried this too and it didn't work since a controller runs before ng-init. And in the angular docs https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngInit, it says ng-init is used for aliasing special properties rather than to initialize values on a scope.